# Setting up TFVS Build with NuGet Packages

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget-package-restore

Hopefully someone out there can help me with this one.  So, here is the problem.  I am trying to get Continuous Integration setup with Team Foundation.  I am using Visual Studio Online.  I am not using Git as my repo.  On my local machine everything builds fine.  On my build service with Team Foundation, I get:

Build
Error: d:\a_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to restore

If I remove the NuGet packages and hard code the Dll's everything runs through just fine.  I have tried a few different things and nothing seems to help.  Yes, before it is suggested, I do have the Nuget Process before the Visual Studio Build Process.  Here are images of my setup if it helps.

[Screenshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY9qL.jpg)

[Screenshot of Advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHsYl.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any help.  I tried doing everything I could before asking.

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Answer (score 0):

Under your "Path to NuGet.config", you specified the test project's packages.config.  You need to change that to the path to the NuGet.config file, not the packages.config file.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It is still not working.  I had to manually add the NuGet.config file.  I copied it over like it suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736107/where-does-nuget-config-file-locate-in-visual-studio-2017-project

Comment: Placing it in %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config wouldn't fix it on the hosted build controller, only on the machine.  You need to put the NuGet.config in source control and update the "Path to NuGet.config" to said path in source control.