# error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'HtmlAgilityPack (>= 1.11.45)' and 'System.Drawing.Common (>= 6.0.0)' for 'net6.0'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, html-agility-pack, .net-6.0

Here's my `csproj` targeting `net6.0`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It needs two libraries [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) and [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/6.0.0). Both are .Net6.0 compatible (according to nuget).
Locally I have .NET SDK installed for  net6.0:

```
dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.400
 Commit:    7771abd614

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Yet, when I run `dotnet restore` I get this error:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Repos\test\test.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'HtmlAgilityPack (>= 1.11.45)' for 'net6.0'.
C:\Repos\test\test.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'System.Drawing.Common (>= 6.0.0)' for 'net6.0'.
  Failed to restore C:\Repos\test\test.csproj (in 104 ms).
```

What am I missing here? I think `dotnet restore` should complete without errors.

Comment: Was not able to repro. Is it possible you have nuget.config file in the solution somewhere? Or disabled some nuget sources?

Comment: Try `dotnet restore -v detailed`. It should then show what it's trying to do.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @PMF's suggestion.

1. Ran `dotnet restore -v detailed`, got the same error.
2. From the output found global `nuget.config` file (`C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`).
3. Checked the config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

4. [Added nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736107/where-is-nuget-config-file-located-in-visual-studio-project):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

After that `dotnet restore` worked as expected.